# C# iTextSharp AutoAdjust column widths

Tags: c#, itext, column-width

Is there a way to adjust columnwidth automatically to fit as much content in them as they can (sort of like double click a column width is a grid control).

At the moment I am setting them as percentages, but as there is different content depending on search criteria, I would like the column width to adjust appropriately.

I am currently setting the widths as below:

```
var table = new PdfPTable(9) {WidthPercentage = 100};
var colWidthPercentages = new[] {6f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 20f, 20f, 8f, 8f, 8f};
table.SetWidths(colWidthPercentages);
```

Does anyone know how to do this, or if not, a way to find out the optimum width a column would need to be to fit its content?

Comment: Here's a better answer but it works only with the AGPL version of iTextSharp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765623/measurestring-with-itext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

XGraphics.MeasureString( string, XFont )

See this question : [Calculate text height based on available width and font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901304/calculate-text-height-based-on-available-width-and-font)

Comment: That's PDFSharp, not ItextSharp