# MeasureString with IText

Tags: c#, itext

I want my columns' width be auto size, but I know this is impossible, so I try to use with the function `MeasureString` without success.

Here is my code:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 72, 72);
doc.Open();
PdfPTable t=new PdfPTable(2);
//Here I want to know the size of the column.
.
.
.
doc.Close();
```

I know I need an object to set the function `MeasureString` on it, but I don't know which object.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `GetWidthPoint(string text, float fontSize)` on an instance of `iTextSharp.text.Font.BaseFont` will return the width of a given string for that particular font.