# Computing the size of some text with PDFSharp

Tags: .net, layout, pdfsharp

How can I get the size of a piece of text as rendered to the page by PDFSharp?

For example, if I've added a user generated (variable height) string to a document and I want to place some new content underneath that, I need to know how much vertical space that has consumed.

For example, in ActionScript you can use [`getTextExtent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashLite/2.0_FlashLiteAPIReference2/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-7782.html) to obtain the metrics of the given piece of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this thread helps:
[Calculate text height based on available width and font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901304/calculate-text-height-based-on-available-width-and-font)